# WildFly 10 HA deploy: not losing sessions

Tags: session, deployment, jboss, wildfly, high-availability

I have been reading posts and documentation all day long about that topic, and still can't find something easy to understand and trust on.

I currently have my webapp deployed on WildFly 10, as a simple war file.

It's an e-commerce website, in production for a few weeks, and every time we need to deploy a new release, well... that's very annoying, because some customers could be shopping right now, and deployment will obviously make them lose their sessions, and that's very bad.

I need a solution to deploy a new war without restarting the application server. At first, I read the docs about clustering (domain configuration over standalone configuration), but I'm not sure that's enough for me...

Imagine the same customer with a few items in the shopping cart (http session), accessing the first node of the cluster. 
Then I put it down, because I'm deploying.
OK, the customer will be redirected to the second node of the cluster but... will the session data still be available? Will he 'lose' the shopping cart items?

I read about sticky sessions, but nothing about configuring them in WildFly. I am on Amazon AWS, so I can use ELB (load balancer), too.
Can you help me understand exactly what I need to learn and use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each WildFly instance will have it's own session id that it keeps in the cookie. This id will only restore the session on the particular node it came from.

Sticky sessions mean that the ELB will always redirect the user to the same node in your cluster so that won't quite solve your problem.

Some things to think about:

**Clustering**

Clustering may help (doesn't need to be domain mode). With HA enabled, the session will be transferred between the nodes automatically so that cookie on the clients browser will be able to restore the session on either node. This of course has the issue where if you upgrade one of the war files first you may have an object that can no longer be de-serialized because it changed.

Clustering WF on AWS is a little tricky as well because you can't use UDP broadcast to discover each other.  We use a database connection to keep track of nodes and do clustering.

**Roll your own**

One option you could do is to roll your own solution to keep just the minimum amount of information on the client as required. Something like:

1. create a record in the database with a GUID.
2. set the GUID to a cookie
3. Save the items in their cart in the database based on the GUID
4. have a filter that checks for the GUID cookie and can restore their cart each time they hit the site.

I've used an approach like this for e-commerce apps in the past. It has another side effect that you now have the person's shopping cart saved in your database and it's easy to see exactly what people were interested in buying.

**Use Tomcat parallel deployment**

Does your application require a full app server? If it is just servlet based you could try using Tomcat and it's parallel deployment functionality. It allows you to deploy your new .war file on top of your old one. It will then keep serving old sessions to the old war but new sessions will go to the new war file.

Parallel deployment is very cool if your app is simple enough to be able to use tomcat.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. Let me ask you about one thing you say:
'We use a database connection to keep track of nodes and do clustering'
Can you please give me more details on how you did that?

Comment: I've been meaning to write a blog post about it. Basically you have to create a jgroups stack that uses JDBC_PING. I have a standalone.xml variant for WF9 that does that here: https://github.com/teacurran/java-experiments/blob/master/server-configs/server_01_wf9_jdbcping.xml Look at the block starting at line 336. You can do the same configuration in WF10. Instead of using UDP to discover each other, each server will will register itself in your database in the JGROUPSPING table.